# NativeScript "Switch" event not working when used inside "Modal"

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to implement filters inside a modal in NativeScript Angular. Everything's been going well so far and I could get value changes for different buttons in the component but "Switch" UI element is not sending an event to Modal's component. I think this might be related to the way how modals work in NativeScript when for example styles won't auto refresh with live sync so you have to close the modal and then reopen it to see changes while you don't have to do this when working with regular components. There are other examples of events not working as expected in Modals but so far I was able to find workarounds. In this case I'd really love to use the Switch element to toggle filtering only recently browsed people.

`tns info`:

```
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
⚠ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 6.7.8 and the latest available version is 6.8.0.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 6.5.12 version and is up to date.
⚠ Update available for component tns-android. Your current version is 6.5.0 and the latest available version is 6.5.3.
✔ Component tns-ios has 6.5.2 version and is up to date.
```

Here's my code that's matching NativeScript's examples:

`customers-filters-modal.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { ModalDialogParams } from "nativescript-angular/modal-dialog";
import { Switch } from "tns-core-modules/ui/switch";
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";

@Component({
    selector: "CustomersFiltersModal",
    templateUrl: "./customers-filters-modal.html"
})
export class CustomersFiltersModalComponent implements OnInit {
    recentlyBrowsed: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private params: ModalDialogParams
    ) {}

    toggleRecentlyBrowsed(args: EventData) {
        const sw = args.object as Switch;
        const isChecked = sw.checked;

        console.log(sw);
        console.log(isChecked);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Init here
    }
}
```

`customers-filters-modal.html`

```
<StackLayout class="filter-item recently-browsed-container">
  <Label class="label" text="Browsing activity"></Label>
  <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*, auto">
    <Label row="0" col="0" text="Recently browsed only"></Label>
    <Switch row="0" col="1" [checked]="recentlyBrowsed (checkedChange)="toggleRecentlyBrowsed($event)"></Switch>
  </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Also if someone can explain why most of events are not working the same way as they sod in regular components here in the modal that can shed some light on the entire app development process for me and improve overall understanding of how the platform works.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was much simpler than expected. It was not working originally due to live sync not syncing properly. Once I restarted `tns run ios` it started sending events and is working as expected now.

Console logs

```
CONSOLE LOG file: src/app/modals/customers-filters/customers-filters-modal.ts:125:16: Switch(88)
CONSOLE LOG file: src/app/modals/customers-filters/customers-filters-modal.ts:126:16: true
```